# Split and combine ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, split, jsoup

Hi guys I have two arrayList that includes one long string in each.

```
ArrayList1 = [Inägogatan 23C (Göteborg) 6210 kr/mån, 69.0 m², 3 rum Eklandagatan 70B (Göteborg) 5594 kr/mån, 57.5 m², 3 rum Uddeholmsgatan 3 D . (Göteborg) 4959 kr/mån, 61.0 m², 3 rum]
ArrayList2 = [Status: Visning påbörjad Status: Visning påbörjad Status: Visning avslutat]
```

I'm trying to split them up so I get this:

```
FinalArrayList = [Inägogatan 23C (Göteborg) 6210 kr/mån, 69.0 m², 3 rum Status: Visning påbörjad, Eklandagatan 70B (Göteborg) 5594 kr/mån, 57.5 m², 3 rum Status: Visning påbörjad, Uddeholmsgatan 3 D . (Göteborg) 4959 kr/mån, 61.0 m², 3 rum Status: Visning avslutat]
```

The only way I can think of way is to somehow split ArrayList1 by "rum" all the time and status in ArrayList2. Is there any smoother way of doing this? :)

Code for filling the arrays with data:

```
deselement = profileURL.getElementsByClass("applications");
statuselement = profileURL.getElementsByClass("status");

            for (Element element : deselement) {
                listDescreption.add(element.getElementsByClass("description").text());
                listStatus.add(element.getElementsByClass("status").text());

                System.out.println(listDescreption);
                System.out.println(listStatus);
       }
}
```

All help is welcome, thanks! :D

Comment: What is the source of those 2 arraylists? And why can't you get them in the way you want, as they really seem to be related. Right now, there isn't a fixed pattern to decide where to split the strings of both list.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What do you mean by split ArrayList? Entire concept of Lists is that it contains separate (split) elements. Do you perhaps get content of arrayLists as one string?

Comment: your arraylist don't look like string.

Comment: I want it to look like this in the FinalArrayList:
    Array1 = [a, b, c]
    Array2 = [1, 2, 3]
    FinalArray = [a 1, b 2, c 3]

Comment: What stops you from doing something like `for (int i=0; i<length; i++){finalArray.add(array1.get(i)+array2.get(i));`?

Comment: @Pshemo This will be the result then, which is not what im looking for:                http://pastebin.com/VYx5rR4u

Comment: In your code you are adding elements to `listDescreption` and `listStatus` inside loop, which may suggest that there are more than one element in your lists. Can you print result of `listDescreption.size` and `listStatus.size()` after your loop will be executed?

Comment: @Pshemo http://pastebin.com/GxbgCwx0

Comment: It is possible to help you with your current code and `split()` string after `, 3 rum` but I strongly suspect that it would be better to replace code like `element.getElementsByClass("description").text()` with more precise code which will select each item from this class and place it in your list as separate element. So could you share HTML code which was selected by `element.getElementsByClass("description")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert strings

```
Inägogatan 23C (Göteborg) 6210 kr/mån, 69.0 m², 3 rum Eklandagatan 70B (Göteborg) 5594 kr/mån, 57.5 m², 3 rum Uddeholmsgatan 3 D . (Göteborg) 4959 kr/mån, 61.0 m², 3 rum

Status: Visning påbörjad Status: Visning påbörjad Status: Visning avslutat
```

to list which will contain

```
Inägogatan 23C (Göteborg) 6210 kr/mån, 69.0 m², 3 rum Status: Visning påbörjad
Eklandagatan 70B (Göteborg) 5594 kr/mån, 57.5 m², 3 rum Status: Visning påbörjad
Uddeholmsgatan 3 D . (Göteborg) 4959 kr/mån, 61.0 m², 3 rum Status: Visning avslutat
```

then you need to split first string on space which has `, 3 rum` right before it, and second string on space which has `Status:` after it, but at the same time we don't want `split` to remove `, 3 rum` nor `Status:`.
We can achieve it with [look-around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) mechanism:

- we need to split first sentence on `"(?<=, 3 rum)\\s"`
- and second sentence on `"(?=\\sStatus:)"`.

Then we can combine n-th element from arrays we got and store them in result list.

So your code can look like:

```
String s1 = "Inägogatan 23C (Göteborg) 6210 kr/mån, 69.0 m², 3 rum Eklandagatan 70B (Göteborg) 5594 kr/mån, 57.5 m², 3 rum Uddeholmsgatan 3 D . (Göteborg) 4959 kr/mån, 61.0 m², 3 rum";
String s2 = "Status: Visning påbörjad Status: Visning påbörjad Status: Visning avslutat";

String[] array1=s1.split("(?<=, 3 rum)\\s");
String[] array2=s2.split("\\s(?=Status:)");

List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i=0; i<array1.length; i++){
    result.add(array1[i]+" "+array2[i]);
}

System.out.println(result);
```

---

But preferred solution would be to let Jsoup split the elements from your lists for you, so instead of adding text from `description` element you should check if each text fragment is not placed in separate tags which you could select and iterate over them and then add them to your list. So instead of

```
listDescreption.add(element.getElementsByClass("description").text());
```

consider using

```
for (Element el : element.select(".description tagWithSingleToken")){
    listDescreption.add(el.text());
}
```

Same for

```
listStatus.add(element.getElementsByClass("status").text());
```

Answer (score 2):

It is actually quite simple :

```
public <T> List<T> merge(List<? extends T> l0, List<? extends T> l1) {
    if (l0.size() != l0.size())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Lists should have the same size");

    List<T> res = new ArrayList<>(l0.size() + l1.size()));
    Iterator<T> it0 = l0.iterator();
    Iterator<T> it1 = l1.iterator();

    while (it0.hasNext() && it1.hasNext()) {
        res.add(it0.next());
        res.add(it1.next());
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Both of the lists have the size of 1. Does even work then? I think the results will be: http://pastebin.com/VYx5rR4u

Comment: @Inc0re "Both of the lists have the size of 1" that is kind of important detail you are sharing. This information wasn't very obvious since elements of `list.toString()` are separated by comma, so it looked like your lists have more than one element.

Comment: Run it, you'll see :D Currently, I'm on a machine with fresh install which does not even have a JDK

Comment: @Pshemo That's why I said it's one long string :) sorry for being unclear

Comment: @Inc0re Just to be clear, can we assume that `[` and `]` is not part of string stored in list?

Comment: @Pshemo new code is added I think there is a way to use .toArray instead of toText(). But it's intressting to know if its possible to fix it anyway. Yeah sure!

Comment: Just use `String.split...`